# Reusable complex read model

Tags: optimization, domain-driven-design, cqrs

In my organisation we have a complex product card with lots of different properties. I could use Steam product card to visualize what I'm talking about: http://store.steampowered.com/app/219740/ (PS: Awesome game, check it).

Product card representation consists of properties such as `title`, `description`, `price` and associations like `screenshots`, `reviews`, `ratings`, `tags` etc. 
Segments of product are used in different parts of application - for example you can find tag lists in user library (where you don't need screenshots).

How would you structure read model here?
a) Try to create small, generic view models (`Screenshot`, `Tag`) and composite them in concrete view (`ProductCard`, `UserLibrary`)? 
b) Create one, god `Product` view model that'll contain every property that is related to product? (performance-wise - doesn't sound very good)
c) Create property tailored view models for each view? If so, how can I avoid code duplications (we use parts of product on EVERY page) if I have to re-use some specific parts (product title, price etc) all across application?
d) ?

I cannot use event listeners as projectors since product state is changed via legacy CRUD application which we cannot modify - we rely on shared database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is...

> Create property tailored view models for each view

Why? Because it's the *simplest and the most maintainable* solution. In a read context, you're just dealing with **read-only** data. You don't need encapsulation or granular representation (a specific model for 'Screenshot' or 'Tag'). That doesn't mean you can't reuse any of the other view models if you already have them and they have the same data, but the main principle here is to create a view model to serve a particular view only.

Duplication doesn't exist in this context, because DRY refers to (same context) behaviour not data.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to avoid code duplication ? Or more specifically why do you want to avoid code duplication in different bounded context ;)... If you create dependencies only based in avoiding code duplication you will create a wrong abstraction (not related to a valid use case).

I will quote Sandi Metz :

> duplication is far cheaper than the wrong abstraction
>
> prefer duplication over the wrong abstraction

[Find more here about wrong abstraction](http://www.sandimetz.com/blog/2016/1/20/the-wrong-abstraction)